# TinyXML2 parser c++ strange tag

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, tinyxml2

Good morning everyone, I have to parse an XML file and I decided to use tinyxml2. I did something and then I stopped because I don't know how can I parse this.

```
<report>
<file name="com.kristanix.android.mahjongsolitaireepic.apk" size="29743 KB" sha1="af054314883c177b2fd533fc907fe5492fc498db" md5="f70d0175469a417facd0e5539c15efdf"/>
<app name="com.kristanix.android.mahjongsolitaireepic.apk" package="com.kristanix.android.mahjongsolitaireepic" version="2.0" minAPI="9">
<permissions>
<permission name="factory_test" used="TRUE" required="FALSE"/>
<permission name="get_tasks" used="TRUE" required="FALSE"/>
<permission name="record_audio" used="TRUE" required="FALSE"/>
<permission name="use_credentials" used="TRUE" required="FALSE"/>
<permission name="wake_lock" used="TRUE" required="FALSE"/>
<permission name="vibrate" used="TRUE" required="FALSE"/>
<permission name="access_wifi_state" used="TRUE" required="FALSE"/>
<permission name="read_contacts" used="TRUE" required="FALSE"/>
<permission name="access_fine_location" used="TRUE" required="FALSE"/>
<permission name="access_network_state" used="TRUE" required="TRUE"/>
<permission name="internet" used="TRUE" required="TRUE"/>
</permissions>
</app>
<analysis>
<virusTotalScore>0/57</virusTotalScore>
<obfuscation>partially</obfuscation>
<appVerification>
Nothing to verify. Application is policy compliant.
</appVerification>
<codeReview>Not Available.</codeReview>
<note/>
</analysis>
</report>
```

My problem is with the tag `<permission`because it's not a child of permissions, neither an attribute. This is the c++ code of my parser

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "tinyxml2.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace tinyxml2;

#ifndef XMLCheckResult
#define XMLCheckResult(a_eResult) if (a_eResult != XML_SUCCESS) { printf("Error: %i\n", a_eResult); return a_eResult; }
#endif

int main() {
    //carico file
    XMLDocument doc;
    doc.LoadFile("test.xml");

    //controllo file
    XMLError eResult = doc.LoadFile("test.xml");
    XMLCheckResult(eResult);

    //minAPI
    int minapi; 
     XMLElement* attributeminapi = doc.FirstChildElement("report")->FirstChildElement("app");
     attributeminapi->QueryIntAttribute("minAPI", &minapi);

     //virus total (è una stringa)
     const char* virustot = doc.FirstChildElement("report")->FirstChildElement("analysis")->FirstChildElement("virusTotalScore")->GetText();

     //obfuscation
     const char* obfuscation = doc.FirstChildElement("report")->FirstChildElement("analysis")->FirstChildElement("obfuscation")->GetText();

     //PERMISSIONS
     //factory test
     XMLElement* fact = doc.FirstChildElement("report")->FirstChildElement("permissions");
     std::string str = fact->Attribute("name");

     return 0;
}
```

The permission parsing gives me an error. Can you help me please? Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the `permissions` (note the "s") container tag here, which, in turn, contains a lot of `permission` tags inside.

```
 XMLElement* fact = doc.FirstChildElement("report")->FirstChildElement("permissions");
```

Then you are trying to access it's `name` attribute:

```
std::string str = fact->Attribute("name");
```

However, `permissions` (note the "s" again) doesn't have any attributes, it's each of the `permission` elements that contain "name". Instead you should iterate over the `permission` elements inside `permissions`, and get the "name" attribute for each of them:

```
for (tinyxml2::XMLElement* child = fact->FirstChildElement(); child != NULL; child = child->NextSiblingElement())
{
    std::string str = child->Attribute("name");
}
```

Comment: It doesn't work, it always gives the same error message

Comment: @ScazzoMatto, which error message exactly? you should update your post with what you've tried and what error you're getting.

Comment: It was my fault because permissions is a child of app. Now it works! thanks a lot. One more question: I have to open 100 files sequentially using doc.LoadFile("name1.xml), doc.LoadFile("name2.xml"). how can i open them with just one command? (like a for)

Comment: @Scazzo, probably you need something like `for(int i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
 {
  std::stringstream sstm;
  sstm << "file" << i << ".txt";
  std::string filename = sstm.str();
 }`